# Splitting a WebService response from a SOAP invocation in XML?

Tags: xml, soap, groovy

I have a BPM Bonita project where I call a webservice through a SOAP invocation, and the displayed output is something like:

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <ns2:getBusinessDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://bpm11.cs.unibo.it">
        <return>
        <name>Clinic Name</name>
        <type>clinic</type>
        <serviceLocation>http://localhost:8888/WebServices/Clinic1</serviceLocation>
        <serviceName>ClinicService</serviceName>
        <bankCode>IT02L1534555346128858689014</bankCode>
        <operatingAreaCodes>1</operatingAreaCodes>
        <operatingAreaCodes>2</operatingAreaCodes>
        <operatingAreaCodes>3</operatingAreaCodes>
        </return>
      </ns2:getBusinessDetailsResponse>
       </S:Body>
      </S:Envelope>
```

which is passed to a Bonita task as a unique String in Groovy code, in this way:

```
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

def output = (DOMSource) response;
String currentTime = output.getNode().childNodes.item(0).textContent;
```

Basically the variable currentTime returns the complete output, but with NO separators whatsoever....

For example:

```
Clinic Namecliniclocalhost:8888 ...etc.etc... IT02L1534555346128858689014123
```

instead of

```
Clinic Name, clinic, localhost:8888 ...etc.
```

Would it be possible to split the SOAP output or add separators?

Thank you very much

Comment: You could do with expanding your examples a little...  But as a complete guess,can you try: `output.getNode().childNodes.item(0).childNodes*.textContent`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use your command I get this: [, Twin towerscar towhttp://localhost:8888/WebServices/CarTow4CarTowServiceIT02L153454534612545868‌​901213] and I still weren't able to separate the response message...

Comment: What is the `response` variable?

Comment: def output = (DOMSource) response;
String businessDetails = output.getNode().childNodes.item(0).childNodes*.textContent;

and the businessDetails variable returns what I pasted before...

Comment: Cool.  What is the response variable? Where do you get it from? How is it defined?

Comment: ok. The response is the resulting output of the webservice invocation "getBusinessDetails". Then Bonita make this variable available in the Groovy editor... 
did I answer your question?

Comment: Does the code below work?

Comment: no it doesn't work as specified below... anyway, this article clarifies in more detail how Bonita dialogs with SOAP envelopes: 

http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/WebServices/TP_Workflow/publish_news.html

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming you're getting a DOMSource (from somewhere), you can do:

```
Map values = use( groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory ) {
    output.node.childNodes.'**'.find { it.name() == 'return' }
                               .findAll { !it.name().startsWith( '#' ) }
                               .collectEntries { [ it.name(), it.text() ] }
}
```

To give you the map:

```
['name':'Clinic Name',
 'type':'clinic',
 'serviceLocation':'http://localhost:8888/WebServices/Clinic1',
 'serviceName':'ClinicService',
 'bankCode':'IT02L1534555346128858689014',
 'operatingAreaCodes':'3']
```

However, if you have access to the XML as a String, it's far nicer in groovy to use `XmlSlurper` like so:

```
Map slurpedValues = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).with { x ->
    x.Body.getBusinessDetailsResponse.return
                                     .children()
                                     .collectEntries { [ it.name(), it.text() ] }
}
```

Which gives the same result

Comment: I have tried the first code snippet using the DOMSource but the task containing this code fails, so basically the code returns nothing… is code snippet complete? which class do I have to import and how do I define the output? thank you very much...